# Minimized javafx stage from another thread

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 threads running, one that is listening in a soket waiting for commandas and another that launch the javafx application

```
public class GraphicInterface extends Application implements Runnable {

  private static Stage primaryStage;


  public static void min(boolean bool) {
        getPrimaryStage().setIconified(bool);
  }

 @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
            GraphicInterface.setPrimaryStage(stage);
            Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
            this.primaryStage = stage;
            sceneParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("...url..."));
            Scene scene = new Scene(sceneParent);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            getPrimaryStage().sizeToScene();
            getPrimaryStage().show();
        }


   @Override
    public void run() {
        launch();
    }

    public static Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        GraphicInterface.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

}
```

The problem is when from the other thread I want to minimize the application calling

```
  GraphicInterface.min(true);
```

I get the error

```
Exception in thread "OTHER THREAD" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = OTHER THREAD
```

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

Solve it by instead of putting `GraphicInterface.min(true)` in the other thread, writing

```
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                GraphicInterface.min();
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running it in JavaFX application thread using:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> GraphicInterface.min(true));
```

*Changes in GUI have to be made only in JavaFX application thread.*

Comment: And how do I call that function?

Comment: When your other thread want to minimize the stage, instead of calling min(true) method, call it inside application thread by typing ***Platform.runLater(() -> { ...yourCodeGoesHere... });***.
Insert your code inside curly brackets { }, in your case:
 GraphicInterface.min(true);

Comment: @danielgon it's not required.
Just copy+paste the line of code I provided.
And feel free to "Accept" my answer if it works, so others can find their answer quicker.